# How to get (feedback)acknowledgments for messages sent to a device from IoT Hub in python?

Tags: python, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I am  able to send messages and reported-properties from iot hub to a simulated device through azure-iot-sdk-python.
Now i wanna get acknowledgments `(success,expired,rejected,purjed,DeliveryCountexceeded)` for messages sent to the device/module from IoT Hub

`ServiceClient.GetFeedbackReceiver` method is available for .Net but i am not able to find a **python sdk** for getting message delivery feedback.

below is code used for sending c2d message

```
from azure.iot.hub import IoTHubRegistryManager
CONNECTION_STRING = ""
DEVICE_ID = ""

registry_manager = IoTHubRegistryManager(CONNECTION_STRING)
data = "Hello.. message from cloud"
props={}
registry_manager.send_c2d_message(DEVICE_ID, data, properties=props)
```

i want to get a feedback when the message sending is failed.. please suggest me a solution.

Thanks in advance.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ServiceClient.GetFeedbackReceiver` method is available for .Net but i am not able to find a **python sdk** for getting message delivery feedback.

You can try  `receive_feedback_notification()` as available on [cloud_to_device_messages_operations.py](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/7ffde49ffc0a7f120e6dc360eeb07dbaad71025b/azure-iot-hub/azure/iot/hub/protocol/operations/cloud_to_device_messages_operations.py)

```
def receive_feedback_notification(self, custom_headers=None, raw=False, **operation_config):
```

Gets the feedback for cloud-to-device messages.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messaging for
more information. This capability is only available in the standard tier IoT Hub. For more information, see [Choose the right IoT Hubtier](https://aka.ms/scaleyouriotsolution).

```
:param dict custom_headers: headers that will be added to the request
:param bool raw: returns the direct response alongside the
deserialized response 
:param operation_config: :ref:`Operation
configuration overrides<msrest:optionsforoperations>`. 
:return: None
or ClientRawResponse if raw=true 
:rtype: None or
~msrest.pipeline.ClientRawResponse 
:raises:
:class:`HttpOperationError<msrest.exceptions.HttpOperationError>`
```

#Construct URL

> url = self.receive_feedback_notification.metadata["url"]

If you want to test feedback notification, refer to [test_iothub_http_runtime_manager.py](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/7ffde49ffc0a7f120e6dc360eeb07dbaad71025b/azure-iot-hub/tests/test_iothub_http_runtime_manager.py)

Comment: when i try below code i am facing below error

Comment: `from azure.iot.hub.iothub_http_runtime_manager import IoTHubHttpRuntimeManager

  
iothub_http_runtime_manager = IoTHubHttpRuntimeManager.from_connection_string(CONNECTION_STRING)


                          feedback = iothub_http_runtime_manager.receive_feedback_notification()


print ( 'feedback message: {0}'.format(feedback) )`

Comment: error:

File "/home/giri/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/iot/hub/protocol/operations/cloud_to_device_messages_operations.py", line 126, in receive_feedback_notification
raise HttpOperationError(self._deserialize, response)
msrest.exceptions.HttpOperationError: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Bad Request'`

Comment: You can refer to similar errors and their solutions on GitHub: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/62373 and https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/issues/825

Comment: All C2D message feedback endpoints are returning Bad Request at the moment  :-(